# What are some annotated sources to guide me through the Federalist Papers and other early American historical documents?

Tags: united-states

As a STEM guy I could very easily read the Federalist Papers and never understand the historical context or the significance of each paper.

Can you recommend a source (audio book, video series, or book) that can "take me gently" through the Federalist Papers and any other early American founding documents?

Comment: you may enjoy Jill LePore's work: https://www.facebook.com/newyorker/videos/an-ode-to-the-federalist-papers-the-political-big-bang/686930632147470/

Comment: For context, you might like “Revolutionary America, 1763-1815: A Political History by Francis D. Cogliano” (2009, 2nd edition) - a concisely written survey text. On the papers, try Pole’s “The Federalist Papers” (2005). Jack Pole passed away in 2010. H-Net’s obituary on him and his final book: http://hnn.us/articles/123313.html

Comment: This may be more topic-based and less detailed than you want, but I like it (paywalled but you can get a free trial): https://www.thegreatcoursesplus.com/books-that-matter-the-federalist-papers